# What is the best practice for code development with git?

Tags: git

I am just getting started with git and am a total noob. Having gone through all of the tutorials, I have no practical experience on how developers actually use git throughout their work day. For example, I have loaded two python scripts I am working on into a bit bucket repository. This is the approach I took to get here in the git bash:

```
cd C:\path\to\my\folder
git init
git add .
git commit -am"Initial Commit"
```

Create a repository in Bit Bucket

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myname/test_project.git
git push -u origin --all
```

Once the repo has been created, I start working on my python scripts. Periodically, say every hour, I update the repo using the following commands:

```
git commit -am"Status Update 1"
git push
```

Is this the recommended workflow for developing code? In other words, am I following best practices for using git on bit bucket, or am I missing out on functionality, or perhaps using git wrong altogether?

Comment: You shouldn’t do periodical commits but rather make commits that semantically group related changes that make sense to be committed as a unit. For example, when you work on a feature, commit the feature as one commit, instead of committing broken ones. Some links to read: http://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/command-line/appendix/best-practices, https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/, http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: I think this question is too open-ended to be on-topic for Stack Overflow. There is no specific problem to be solved. It might even be too open-ended for [tag:programmers.se]. Could you please state some specific concern that prompted you to ask this question?

Comment: @200_success "Too broad" or "primarily opinion-based" also applies to programmers.

Comment: If you actually _need_ "Save everything regularily" then you should have your operating system help you with scheduled backups, like Time Machine under OS X.  You will with experience find that version control is for saying _which_ of the various instances your filesystem was in during your development was actually important and why.  Fow now just say "When I finished a chunk of work that would make a good commit message, then commit!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to commit logically related changes,
with a commit message describing what the commit is about.
(A commit message like "Status Update N" is outright horrible.
See [this article](http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/) about writing good commit messages.)

That way,
your revision history will read like a sequence of logical steps in the evolution of the project,
and if you ever need to roll back to a specific point in the past,
you will be able to find the right commits easier.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend installing a git app on your computer and setup an account on a git storage site then when you develop on your computer and commit to the git storage site thus storing your scripts.

Comment: OP is already using Git with Bitbucket, so what exactly are you suggesting?

Comment: using git and github allows for better version management and storage of development files.

Comment: Is your point that GitHub is better than Bitbucket (which is very subjective), or are you just not reading the question and my comment properly?